# MacBook Air 2011 - External Display

Tags: macbook-pro, display

I currently have a MacBook Air 13" 2011.

I want to connect two external Displays. Does it work? I think it can speak to two Displays. When the internal Display is closed, it should be possible to connect another display to have two one!

I want to buy a Dock where i can close the display and have two external ones.

Does anyone know if this solution works?

Comment: There's only 1 Thunderbolt port for Air mid 2011

Comment: [This guy](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vIVZI1cFiAw) did it with a MacBook Pro and an USB to DVI adapter. Maybe this also works with the Air.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [specs](http://www.apple.com/macbookair/specs.html) say that it only supports a single external display.

Answer (score -1):

Check out the [Air Display](http://avatron.com/apps/air-display) app.